# Printing argv[0] in nasm/Windows?

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm, argv

With online help, I was able to write [nasm code](https://github.com/mcandre/scriptname/blob/master/nasm/freebsd/scriptname.asm) in Mac OS X resulting in an executable that prints its own filename, `argv[0]` in equivalent C code. When I use the same code in Windows, I want it to print the programs name:

```
C:\> nasm -f win32 -o scriptname.obj scriptname.asm
C:\> golink /fo scriptname.exe scriptname.obj /console kernel32.dll Msvcrt.dll

GoLink.Exe Version 0.27.0.0 - Copyright Jeremy Gordon 2002/12 - JG@JGnet.co.uk
Output file: scriptname.exe
Format: win32 size: 2,048 bytes
C:\> scriptname.exe
Program: scriptname.exe
```

But what it actually prints is emptiness:

```
C:\> scriptname.exe
Program:
```

Specs:

- golink 0.27.0.0
- nasm 2.10.05
- Windows 7 Professional x64
- MacBook Pro 2009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call GetStdHandle and save the returned value to ecx, ecx is a volatile register, the value will not be saved across calls unless you push/pop it.  Your first call to WriteConsoleA uses it and clobbers it so the next call, ecx is not what you expect.

*** EDIT ***
I was bored so here is working code:

```
[bits 32]

section .data

program db "Program: ", 0
programlen equ $-program

nl db "", 13, 10, 0
nllen equ $-nl

section .bss

buf resd 1
argc resd 1
argv resb 255

section .text

global Start
extern GetStdHandle
extern __getmainargs
extern WriteConsoleA
extern ExitProcess

strlen:             ; eax: a string ending in 0
push eax            ; cache eax

.strloop:

mov bl, byte [eax]
cmp bl, 0
je .strret          ; return len if bl == 0
inc eax             ; else eax++
jmp .strloop

.strret:

pop ebx             ; ebx = cached eax
sub eax, ebx        ; eax -= ebx
ret                 ; eax = len

Start:

push 0
push buf
push argv
push argc
call __getmainargs
add esp, 16         ; clear stack (4 * 4 arguments)

push -11            ; get stdout
call GetStdHandle
mov esi, eax
add esp, 4          ; clear stack (4 * 1 argument)

push 0              ; null
push buf            ; [chars written]
push programlen
push program
push esi            ; stdout
call WriteConsoleA
add esp, 20         ; clear stack (4 * 5 arguments)

mov edx, [argv]
mov eax, [edx]   ; <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
call strlen
push 0              ; null
push buf            ; [chars written]
push eax            ; len argv[0]
push dword [edx]    ;<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<       ; argv[0]
push esi            ; stdout
call WriteConsoleA
add esp, 20         ; clear stack (4 * 5 arguments)

push 0              ; null
push buf            ; [chars written]
push nllen
push nl
push esi            ; stdout
call WriteConsoleA
add esp, 20         ; clear stack (4 * 5 arguments)

push 0
call ExitProcess


D:\NASM Projects\ReadArgs>ReadArgs.exe
Program:  ReadArgs.exe

D:\NASM Projects\ReadArgs>
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. How would you change the code to correct for this?

Comment: save it to a non volatile register - esi, ebx, edi or just push ecx before a call and pop it after words

Comment: I'm using named pointers instead of volatile registers, and now my code is printing argv[0] as a strange pair of ascii characters.

Comment: Ah, finally! Yeah, it turns out I wasn't fully dereferencing the argv pointer properly.

Answer (score 2):

The `argc` and `argv` arguments are for C based programs only. Assembly based programs are must use `__getmainargs` or `__wgetmainargs` functions from the C library to generate those variables like they are internally used by C based programs. See below MSDN article for details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770599.aspx

Comment: In Linux and Mac OS X, the stack pointer `esp` is filled with the equivalent of `argc` and `argv` by default. Is this not done in Windows?

Comment: No, Linux does things differently (Better IMHO).  All this info IS available in the PEB and the way you get args is with GetCommandLine or if you need an argv array of strings then CommandLineToArgvW

Comment: @Jay, I'm so close to printing `argv[0]` in nasm/Windows using `__getmainargs`, but the code still prints emptiness. Help! https://github.com/mcandre/scriptname/blob/master/nasm/windows/scriptname.asm

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes and no. In Linux, at the `_start:` label, `argc` is at `[esp]` and `argv[0]` is at `[esp + 4]`. If your code works, this must also be true of Mac OSX. By doing `-e main` on the ld command line, essentially `main` is lying about its name. It isn't really a "C style main". This label is jumped to, not called. If `main` (or _main, for 'doze and Mac OSX) is called by "C startup code" (crt2.o), then there's a return address on the stack, so `argc` is at `[esp + 4]` and `argv[0]` is at `[esp + 8]`. Also, as Tim tells you at news:comp.lang.asm.x86 `argv` is a `**` - a "pointer to pointer" - so you also need the `mov ebx, [ebx]` (a "de-reference"). I'm pretty sure in Windows, our code is called regardless of what we name the entrypoint. Can you get it to work that way?

EDIT: Well this has pretty much been beaten to death, and "solved"(?), but I got bored, too. This works in Linux, and "might" be portable.

```
;  prints its own name (possibly portable?)
; nasm -f elf32 myprog.asm
; nasm -f macho myprog.asm --prefix _
; nasm -f win32 myprog.asm --prefix _
; gcc -o myprog myprog.o(bj) (-m32 for 64-bit  systems)

global main
extern printf

section .data
    prog db `Program: %s \n`, 0

section .text
main:
    mov eax, [esp + 8]
    mov eax, [eax]
    push eax
    push prog
    call printf
    add esp, 4 * 2
    ret
;----------------------
```

Comment: You tell me! Feel free to patch my code (https://github.com/mcandre/scriptname/tree/master/nasm), and once you get it working in both Mac OS X and Windows, submit a pull request.

Comment: Can't run Mac OS X and won't run Windows, so I can't help you there. Code much like you've got works in Linux. I think to make it "portable", your best bet is to use gcc to invoke ld (nothing to "compile" really) - link in that "C startup code" in all cases.